# Why the DupeFilter and RFPDupefilter are not middleware objects?

Tags: python, scrapy

While working on my crawler, I needed to implement a persistent duplicate filter that will detect already scraped items not only to drop them, but also to create a new relationship in DB. I actually store both items and researches (N to N relationship), thus if an items is already knew (I don't care about the update), I still want it to be associated to my new research.

Anyway, I found a solution by overriding the RFPDupeFilter.

Yet, I spent hours digging into Spider Middleware and Downloader Middleware as I was convinced the solution was to implement a new middleware - the scrapy architecture shared here seems straightforward https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#data-flow.
And finally I saw references to DupeFilter and RFPDupeFilter that is indeed exactly what I need.

Question is: why those filters are not implemented as middlewares? What makes those filter so specific that they couldn't fit the middleware interface?

Thank you for the clarification

Comment: I guess this is a question for [/r/scrapy/](https://www.reddit.com/r/scrapy/), not StackOverflow. One thing though, the `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` is about filtering requests, not items ; and is used by the requests scheduler.